# Generating function - technical issue.

Tags: generating-functions

Which sequence is generated by $\frac{{5x - 3{x^2}}}{{{{(1 - x)}^3}}}$?

We know that:
$$\frac{1}{{{{(1 - x)}^3}}} = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {j + 2}  \\
   2  \\
\end{array}} \right){x^j}} $$

So we have:

$$(5x - 3{x^2}) \cdot \sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {j + 2}  \\
   2  \\
\end{array}} \right){x^j}} $$

Now it's easy to see that for $x^k$, $a_k$ can be defined by:

$$5\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {k + 1}  \\
   2  \\
\end{array}} \right) - 3\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   k  \\
   2  \\
\end{array}} \right)$$

Because we "used" $x^{k-1}$ and $x^{k-2}$ there may be a problem for $k=0,1$ and I've been told I need to check it directly. Can you help me with that?

Comment: It is generated by $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} k(k+4)x^{k}$

Comment: Cool. How did you figure it out?

Comment: Why don't you check the terms $k=0$ and $k=1$ by yourself?

Comment: By looking at it :) Actually, all it takes is some algebra, but I could almost instantly tell what would generate it.

Comment: Because I'm not certain what should I do exactly. Is it just evaluating the last expression?

Comment: Expand it as partial fraction to obtain $\frac{3}{(x-1)}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{2}{(x-1)^3}$. Then solve each separately and add up.

Comment: @AnnieOK A tip: you can use e.g. `{k + 1 \choose 2}` with braces around it for combinations; that way you don't have to have a whole bunch of messy `\begin{array}` and `\end{array}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overthinking things.  First of all,
\begin{align*}
5 {k + 1 \choose 2} - 3{k \choose 2}
&= 5\frac{(k+1)k}{2} - 3\frac{k(k-1)}{2} \\
&= \frac{5}{2} k^2 + \frac52 k - \frac32k^2 + \frac32 k \\
&= 4k + k^2 \\
&= k(k + 4) \\
\end{align*}

So your sequence is $a_k = k(k+4)$.  Second of all, they probably want you to plug in $k = 0$ and $k = 1$, giving
$$
a_0 = 0, a_1 = 5
$$
Now check that these particular cases line up with the series expression you had before
$$(5x - 3{x^2}) \cdot \sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {j + 2}  \\
   2  \\
\end{array}} \right){x^j}}. $$

That is, check that the series above starts out with $0 + 5x^1 + \cdots$.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that

$$\frac{{5x - 3{x^2}}}{{{{(1 - x)}^3}}} = \frac{3}{(x-1)}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{2}{(x-1)^3}$$

And,

$$\frac{3}{(x-1)} = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-3)x^k$$

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}= \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)x^k$$

$$\frac{-2}{(x-1)^3}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k(k+1)(k+2)$$

Add them up and you get

$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} k(k+4)x^{k}$$